# Computing conditional distribution of uniform distribution over a disc.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Assume the random variable $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the disc $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leqslant 1\}$ and on $[-1,1]^2$, respectively.
>
> In both cases determine the the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$.

**My attempt:**

$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\text{area of B}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$  if $(x,y)\in B$

$P(A)=\int\int_{A}f(x,y)dxdy=\int\int\frac{1}{2\pi}=\frac{\text{area of A}}{2\pi}$

I need to compute:

$P(Y\in dy|X=x)=f_{Y|X}(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}$

where $f_{X}(x)=\int_B f(x,y)dy$

However it is precisely this last integral that is difficult for me to define, since I am integrating on a disc. On which domain shall I integrate in what concerns $Y$?

**Question:**

How should I solve this problem? Am I right insofar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area is $\pi$ not $2\pi$. $f_X(x)=\int f(x,y)dy=\int_{-\sqrt {1-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt {1-x^{2}}} \frac 1 {\pi} dy=\frac {2\sqrt {1-x^{2}}} {\pi}$ for $|x| \leq 1$. Also $\int \frac 1 {\sqrt {1-x^{2}}}dx=\arcsin \, x$. Can you take it from here?

For the square you have to integrate w.r.t $y$ from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: So $f_{Y|X}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. How do I compute the cumulative distribution of $f_{Y|X}$? Which boundaries shall I define for $X$ and $Y$ repectively?

Comment: You have already written the formula for $f_{Y|X}$. In both cases $X$ and $Y$ range from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Is this integral $\int_{-1}^y \int_{-1}^x f_{Y|X}dxdy=\int_{-1}^y \int_{-1}^x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}dxdy
$ the  cumulative distribution?

Comment: In the case of the square, yes. That is the cumulative DF but don't use the same letters for the limits of integration and the variables of integration.

Comment: After integrating I got $F_{X|Y}=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(x)(y+1)$. Is it right?

Comment: I am not talking about the square but about the computation of the cumulative distribution of $f_{Y|X}$ on the unit circle. Which boundaries shall I set for each random variables? [-1,x] and  [-1,y]?

Comment: Your formula is correct for the circle also.